# How do I enable verbose mode at boot?

Tags: boot, grub2

How to make natty boot in verbose mode. Changing option `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="splash quiet` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""` in `/etc/default/grub` doesn't effect in natty.

Comment: I am not sure, but try it. On the grub options  remove  quiet.

Comment: Did you run "sudo update-grub" after making changes to /etc/default/grub ?

Comment: @karthick87: Yes, I did it.

Answer (score 21):

Try `nosplash debug`. If you want output from upstart too, add `--verbose`

Comment: can you check to see if these options were passed to the running kernel? `cat /proc/cmdline` will show you what the kernel actually booted with.

Comment: I didn't understand where I can add `--verbose`, can you explain yourself better?

Comment: @MarioPalumbo this question is about changing the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` variable in `/etc/default/grub`, so that's the context of the answer.

Answer (score 13):

Changing

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

to

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""
```

in `/etc/default/grub` is correct, but you also need to run `update-grub` for it to take effect.

Answer (score 3):

Hit <kbd>Esc</kbd> any time to see the text.
For permanent changes, uninstall [all plymouth themes](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=plymouth-theme), including text ones, and in `/etc/grub/default` uncomment the line to enable console.

Comment: Uncomment `GRUB_TERMINAL=console` in /etc/grub/default works in my laptop but grub resolution decreased to 800x600.

Comment: You can fix resolution right there. GRUB_GFXMODE=whatever. Note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE. You can see them in GRUB console with the command `vbeinfo'

Comment: `vbeinfo` is not found on my system [and apparently isn't in the repo], but this works: `sudo hwinfo --framebuffer`

Comment: vbeinfo is not part of linux: it is a command that you can run from grub screen