# Grub Display Settings

Tags: boot, grub2, display, macbook-pro

I have just installed Ubuntu 20.04 in an MacBookPro 2012 retina.  The screen is broken so it's useless and I connect via HDMI to a Samsung monitor, this solution has worked well up to now.
During the installation process all went well.  I turn on the computer close the lid, and it automatically goes to the attached monitor.  The installation process worked well like this and it went smoothly, all on my monitor.  After reboot though, the boot process crashes.
I do the same thing as always, which is to turn the computer on, close the lid, it goes to the monitor.  I see grub and its options, select Ubuntu and after a couple of seconds boot crashes and I'm left with a dark screen and the fans whirring very fast.
I have tried recovery mode, gone to shell/terminal and tried xrandr but it says it can't open display.
I have tried installing xorg and other things but it starts to install and as the screen moves up it crashes.
I don't understand how the installation USB could work perfectly and now the full install won't.
Any advice on how to solve this problem ??
I tried reinstalling and it's the same thing. All is well up to Grub and then it always crashes.
I was thinking that maybe there is some kind of setting in grub that I can change to make it work, on boot initially and then in ubuntu once it opens, any suggestions ??
I also tried nomodeset on grub boot kernel options.
Thanks
Manuel

Comment: First You can enable [grub verbose](https://askubuntu.com/questions/39057/how-do-i-enable-verbose-mode-at-boot) mode to see if there are some useful messages printed during boot.

Comment: Hi, I did but no error, it seemed ok all green, and suddenly screen went black and it froze again. I disconnected the monitor and it went through the boot process fine, I can see parts of the screen and managed to log into my install with the monitor disconnected using the broken screen.  When I connect the monitor, it crashes, must be a driver issue, I can open the terminal window (all on the broken screen) and type the commands to install a driver, but what should I install and what command should I type ??  Its a mid 2012 15 inch MBP retina with a GeForce GT 650M video card.