# Is the monitor ubuntu boots on hardwired during installation?

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi, monitor

I installed 20.04 on a new machine using an old monitor connected to HDMI. After it worked, I moved it to a different location and plugged a UHD resolution monitor into the display port connection on this machine. When it boots, I get a BIOS message about how to enter the boot menu or setup on the monitor, then it just sits there till the graphical interface comes up (which does display fine on the new display port monitor). No ubuntu logo or anything during the boot, just the text that the BIOS put on the screen the whole time. Is there some way to convince it to show boot messages on the display port? Grub options to change or something?

Machine: ASRock AMD Barebone 4X4 BOX-4800U with Ryzen cpu. (UEFI only)

Install media: ubuntu-20.04-desktop-amd64.iso

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I enable verbose mode at boot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/39057/how-do-i-enable-verbose-mode-at-boot)

Comment: Nope, even the splash screen doesn't display, but it turns out there may be something wrong with the computer itself, I've just sent it back to newegg for a replacement (not because of this, a more serious issue involving the screen going completely blank when I plug something into a usb port :-).