# grub2: error: can't allocate initrd - chainload an NTFS partition from FAT32 without errors on initial ramdisk (initrd) file

Tags: boot, partitioning, 20.04, grub2, uefi

The OS with `Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS Desktop 64-bit` is located in the gpt2 partition with the filesystem NTFS.

This is the structure of the gpt1 partition with the filesystem FAT32:

```
.
├── boot
│   └── grub
│       └── grub.cfg
└── efi
    └── boot
        ├── bootx64.efi
        ├── grubx64.efi
        └── mmx64.efi

4 directories, 4 files
```

This is the grub menù of the NTFS partition (default grub.cfg):

```
if loadfont /boot/grub/font.pf2 ; then
    set gfxmode=auto
    insmod efi_gop
    insmod efi_uga
    insmod gfxterm
    terminal_output gfxterm
fi

set menu_color_normal=white/black
set menu_color_highlight=black/light-gray

set timeout=5
menuentry "Ubuntu" {
    set gfxpayload=keep
    linux   /casper/vmlinuz  file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed maybe-ubiquity quiet splash ---
    initrd  /casper/initrd
}
menuentry "Ubuntu (safe graphics)" {
    set gfxpayload=keep
    linux   /casper/vmlinuz  file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed maybe-ubiquity quiet splash nomodeset ---
    initrd  /casper/initrd
}
menuentry "OEM install (for manufacturers)" {
    set gfxpayload=keep
    linux   /casper/vmlinuz  file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed only-ubiquity quiet splash oem-config/enable=true ---
    initrd  /casper/initrd
}
grub_platform
if [ "$grub_platform" = "efi" ]; then
menuentry 'Boot from next volume' {
    exit 1
}
menuentry 'UEFI Firmware Settings' {
    fwsetup
}
fi
```

If the grub.cfg file (FAT32 partition) contains:

```
search --no-floppy --set=root --fs-uuid 2E92F36515DD4A5A
chainloader /EFI/BOOT/BOOTx64.EFI
boot
```

After making a choice from the grub selection menu, placed in the default grub.cfg file (NTFS partition) which is the same as the default contained within an iso image of `Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS Desktop 64-bit`, the error message appears:

```
error: can't allocate initrd.
Press any key to continue...
```

I have to underline that the NTFS partition bootloader starts correctly with the `chainloader` command, otherwise I would not have seen the grub selection menu, it is the `initrd` command that gives an error.

If instead the grub.cfg file (FAT32 partition) contains:

```
search --no-floppy --set=root --fs-uuid 2E92F36515DD4A5A
configfile /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

After the selection menu, everything works correctly, therefore the initrd command no longer gives an error.

What's wrong with running the NTFS partition bootloader to boot `initrd` using the default grub.cfg file inside it?
I have tested that if partition 2 has Windows, using `chainloader` everything works correctly.

UPDATE 1:
I tried to swap partitions, the error persists.

UPDATE 2:
I would like to get more detailed error output from the `initrd` command but I don't know [how to do it](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1399619/initrd-casper-initrd-verbose-output).
I have tried

```
linux   /casper/vmlinuz file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed nosplash debug ignore_loglevel ---
initrd  /casper/initrd
```

but the error output is still the same, no rows added.

UPDATE 3:
Summarizing and clarifying what I am going to do, I from the partition with FAT32 do the chainload of the bootloader located on the NTFS partition.
If I boot the NTFS partition directly from BIOS, everything works, if instead I chainload starting from the FAT32 partition, problems appear.
Everything works correctly even if I call the menu of the grub.cfg (NTFS partition) using the `configfile` command rather than the `chainloader` command inside the `grub.cfg` file of the FAT32 partition, of which I have already shown the lines it contains.

UPDATE 4:
I am going to use the `chainloader` command anyway for generalization reasons, even being able to use the `configfile` command that would solve the problem, because I would have the possibility to execute the same command both to start a partition with Windows and Ubuntu.

UPDATE 5:
The `ntfs` module is already built into the bootloader of both partitions. The `lsmod` command confirmed this. In any case I have tried to insert `insmod ntfs` in the `grub.cfg` files of both partitions and, as expected, the error does not change.

UPDATE 6:
I don't boot NTFS partition directly from BIOS, because UEFI on older computers cannot read NTFS directly.

UPDATE 7:
I HAVE DISCOVERED AN ERROR! Before I didn't notice it because it lasts a fraction of a second. But with a video from the phone, which I had to set to 60 fps to be able to catch the error, I recorded it, then took it to the PC, from the PC I took a screenshot of that video fragment, then rotated it and cropped with gimp.
The error is as follows:

```
error: can't find command `grub_platform`.
```

Here is the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: is this part of a `menuentry` in the grub.cfg? is there anything else in the menuentry?

Comment: and to confirm, there is a UEFI GRUB installed on the second partition in `/efi/boot/bootx64.efi`? Can you boot to the second partition directly from the BIOS?

Comment: @Esther Yes, then I not understand why not with chainloader.

Comment: After booting run `lsblk` and add to your question. There might be some details there. Also did you try running boot-repair? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1104855/how-to-make-grub-menu-appear-instead-grub-minimal-bash-like-in-booting/1105737#1105737

Comment: @Esther The `grub.cfg` file that I showed, which is that of the `FAT32` partition, does not contain the menu. The `grub.cfg` that contains the menu, which is located in the `NTFS` partition, I have not shown it, as it is the same as that of default contained within an iso image of `Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Desktop 64-bit`.

Comment: how large is the `initrd` on the Ubuntu system?

Comment: @Esther 80,7 MB

Comment: try [how to enable extra verbose mode when booting](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/271798/how-can-i-activate-extra-verbose-mode-debugging-mode-during-debian-boot) or [enable verbose mode at boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/39057/how-do-i-enable-verbose-mode-at-boot) to maybe be able to see what is happening? you can also try putting `debug` at the beginning of your grub.cfg on the first grub and in the menuentry of the second grub to see Grub debug messages.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I have runned `lsblk` in grub terminal but `error: can't find command 'lsblk'`.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I am not in a live session, it could not start as it crashes first, on error in initial RAMdisk (initrd).

Comment: @Esther In your link there is an answer that says: "Try `nosplash debug`. If you want output from upstart too, add `--verbose`".
I added `nosplash debug` and the output stays the same (ie it doesn't work) but i didn't understand where I can add `--verbose`, the answer didn't explain anything.
What is an `upstart`?

Comment: I have tried `linux /casper/vmlinuz file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed nosplash debug ignore_loglevel ---` but the output is the same, no rows added.

Comment: what grub command are you using? on update7. please provide us content of `cat /path/to/40_custom` file.

Comment: I am using the commands present in the `grub.cfg` file present in the `FAT32` partition. i not have `40_custom` file. If you mean the content of grub.cfg, that is present in the question.

Comment: @MarioPalumbo i think that's your problem, try to add custom grub. please edit etc/grub.d/40_custom and add lines menuentry "Chainload to grub in /dev/sda8" { set root=(hd0,8) chainloader +1 } and run `sudo update-grub` and then boot it again

Comment: @MarioPalumbo i guess you try to load a persistence file. i think you forgot `boot=casper quiet persistent`.

Comment: I not have eight partition but only two partitions: /dev/sda1 and /dev/sda2.

Comment: I not have /etc folder on PenDrive but is a PenDrive with an Ubuntu installer (on NTFS partition) and command chainloader is on grub.cfg of the FAT32 partition.

Comment: @MarioPalumbo change the number partition in yourself. did you try to add `boot=casper quiet persistent` in your grub?.

Comment: What's the sense of making partition 2 become partition 8?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135218/discussion-between-mario-palumbo-and-abu-ahmed-al-khatiri).

Answer (score 0):

You're running Linux on NTFS, is that correct?

If so, GRUB probably can't read NTFS by default and so can't access the initrd file. According to the Grub2 documentation https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/html_node/Chain_002dloading.html I would try adding that `insmod ntfs` to the appropraite menuentry.

If that's not correct, you should clarify your question with the exact (relevant) configuration stanzas for the configuration files.

I also can't tell if the error is coming from GRUB or the Linux kernel. Does the kernel start to load at all?

It's also not clear to me why you want to chainload to another boot loader to load Linux instead of just loading the kernel from the NTFS partition directly, but given that you've installed Linux on NFTS I'll assume you have a reason for doing this.

Comment: I from the partition with FAT32 do the chainload of the bootloader located on the NTFS partition.
If I boot the NTFS partition directly from BIOS, everything works, if instead I chainload starting from the FAT32 partition, problems appear.
Everything works correctly even if I call the menu of the grub.cfg (configfile command) located on the NTFS partition, starting from the grub.cfg of the FAT32 partition, of which in my question I have shown the lines it contains.

Comment: @MarioPalumbo did you try adding `insmod ntfs` before the rest of the lines you posted?

Comment: No, I will try.

Comment: Yesterday I already made all the necessary edits to specify the question in depth.

Comment: The `ntfs` module is already built into the bootloader of both partitions. The `lsmod` command confirmed this.
In any case I have tried to insert `insmod ntfs` in the `grub.cfg` files of both partitions and, as expected, the error does not change.
However, I have to underline that the NTFS partition bootloader starts correctly with the `chainloader` command, it is the `initrd` command that gives an error, and I would also like to know how to make the error message more detailed.

Comment: I have edited and detailed the question as best I could, that's the best I can do. Now I need you to try to understand the question well, there is nothing else I can specify, I have already written all the writable in the question.

Comment: Hi @MarioPalumbo, I'm not sure you've posted the necessary configuration blocks. I don't see any 'menuitem' entries, for instance. However, if I understand, you want to chainload from drive2/NTFS, but you're loading from drive1/FAT. I think you need to chainload the other drive, like `chainloader (hd1,gpt1)/path/to/grub.efi`.

Does this help? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/343632/uefi-chainloading-grub-from-grub

I think I'm doing 'answers' wrong so I'll fix my answer or delete this if I can, after you let me know.

Comment: `It's also not clear to me why you want to chainload to another boot loader to load Linux instead of just loading the kernel from the NTFS partition directly`.
Because UEFI on older computers cannot read NTFS directly.
I am going to use the `chainloader` command anyway for generalization reasons.

Comment: Did the link I provided help at all?

Comment: `I think you need to chainload the other drive`. But the partition with the bootloader is on the same disk (PenDrive) as the partition doing the chainloading, it is only the partition that changes.

Comment: I have tried to chainload (hd1,gpt1), the error is the same.

Comment: @rand'Chris `Did the link I provided help at all?` No.

Comment: is it time to report the bug to Ubuntu in your opinion? I see there is no solution through the `chainloader` command. The most obvious ways I have tried them all.

Comment: Unfortunately I provide with a condition that executes the `configfile` command if the `grub.cfg` file exists and the `chainloader` command if it does not exist (as in the case of Windows). I consider this question as `unsolved`.

Comment: @MarioPalumbo, rather than issue UPDATE messages, I would suggest you simplify your question and include the complete configuration sections. It is too difficult to understand what your configuration is. The chainloader is used to boot a different boot manager, but you said you're loading something on an NTFS partition and the configuration you show has you trying to chainload something from a FAT32 partition. This makes no sense to me. I think you need to ask about GRUB at the link I provided, as this is not a problem with Ubuntu.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/697608/grub2-error-cant-allocate-initrd-chainload-an-ntfs-partition-from-fat32-wit

Answer (score 0):

For those of you searching for why grub is saying it "can't allocate initrd" after you installed another OS, I found that that the boot order in BIOS was set to load the new OS. Once I unplugged the external drive, it gave me a grub recovery. I had to learn that to get inch grub and it was all for naught.

After painful hours of tearing my hair out, I found the solution thanks to [the people over on Hiveon](https://hiveon.com/forum/t/error-can-t-allocate-initrd/67243/4). I hope this saves you hours of searching and pain.